# The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port? FAQ

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to kubernetes . I got the below error while interacting with the cluster `kubectl get nodes` .

ERROR:
`The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?`

Answer (score 1):

After search in the internet i fixed my issues .

```
#sudo cp /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/
```

`#sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/admin.conf`

`#export KUBECONFIG=$HOME/admin.conf`

Comment: There is clear [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#more-information) step on to make kubectl work for your non-root user run these commands.

Answer (score 0):

When  **there is clear instructions by `kubeadm init` to execute following commands as an regular user, if you miss runing them you end up with issue reported**.

```
To make kubectl work for your non-root user, run these commands, which are also part of the kubeadm init output:

mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

**You should check back the logs at `kubeadm init` time and you will find similar as below asking to execute the command.**

```
[addons] Applied essential addon: CoreDNS
[addons] Applied essential addon: kube-proxy

Your Kubernetes control-plane has initialized successfully!

To start using your cluster, you need to run the following as a regular user:

  mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
  sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
  sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config

You should now deploy a Pod network to the cluster.
Run "kubectl apply -f [podnetwork].yaml" with one of the options listed at:
  /docs/concepts/cluster-administration/addons/

You can now join any number of machines by running the following on each node
as root:

  kubeadm join <control-plane-host>:<control-plane-port> --token <token> --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:<hash>
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with the use-context in kubectl command.Please check the same in kubeconfig file.

Answer (score 0):

Try both of this, It could be either one of them

1. Check if minikube is running. If you don't know what minikube is then just google it, install it before running kubectl commands. If you do have minikube then check the status of the minikube `minikube status`. Start minikube with `minikube start` and then try running the `kubectl` commands
2. Run this command `sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock`

Answer (score -1):

Your kubectl is probably not referring to right kubeconfig file or the kubeconfig file does not right details.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you not set environment variables, try this:

```
export KUBERNETES_MASTER=http://MasterIP:8080
```

`MasterIP` is your Kubernetes master IP

Answer (score -1):

```
Kubeadm init cidr <ip address> --ignore-preflight=all
```

After that you will get the token.

If you still don't get the token upgrade your aws ec2 instance configuration from t2.medium to t2.large or t2.xlarge

After that you will get it node connected and don't forget to associate elastic ip

Comment: What in the text of the question indicated that they are using AWS?